# Prove $(2^{n}+1)=Q(2^{m}+1)+2^{r}+1$ if r is even and $n=qm+r$, $r<m$

Tags: number-theory

Prove $(2^{n}+1)=Q(2^{m}+1)+2^{r}+1$ if r is even and $n=qm+r$, $r<m$

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant $q$ is even and $Q$ is integer, in that case as $2^m+1 \mid 2^{qm}-1$ so, $2^n+1 \equiv 2^r+1 (\mod 2^m+1)$. (Note even if $q$ isn't even and your problem is correct then $2^m+1\mid 2^{qm}-1 \implies q$ is even)

Comment: You can use `a\equiv b\pmod{cd}`: $a\equiv b\pmod{cd}$. (As usual, the curly braces are unnecessary when there's a single character inside.)

Comment: Thank you, this is problem 4 from chapter 2 The Mathematics of Ciphers: Number Theory and RSA by S.C. Coutinho.